# QGIS Value relation bracket removal

Tags: qgis, valuerelation

When using Value relation fields and multiple selection QGIS adds {} brackets in the table. When exporting the data to be used in reports and the like these brackets are not desirable. Is there a way to remove them efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new virtual field with this expression and replace `fieldname` with the name of the Value relation field:

```
regexp_replace ("fieldname",'{|}|"','')
```

[image]

Comment: Would be best if it was possible to remove them altogether for easier post processing and not needing yet another field. But this definitely works for now. Thanks a lot!